# Why is a Typescript project reference using the parent tsconfig file instead of the reference's own tsconfig file?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, strict

I have two projects: `app` and `lib`. `app` depends on `lib`.

`app` is a strict Typescript project, `lib` **does not work** with strict.

I've wired them together using Typescript Project References:

[./tsconfig.json](https://github.com/gaggle/monorepo-tsconfig-experiment/blob/main/tsconfig.json)

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "./apps/app" },
    { "path": "./libs/lib/" }
  ]
```

[./apps/app/tsconfig.json](https://github.com/gaggle/monorepo-tsconfig-experiment/blob/main/apps/app/tsconfig.json)

```
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../libs/lib/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
```

[./libs/lib/tsconfig.json](https://github.com/gaggle/monorepo-tsconfig-experiment/blob/main/libs/lib/tsconfig.json)

```
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "strict": false
  },
```

But when I run `app` I get a failure because `lib` code is being run as if strict is true:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../../libs/lib/src/index.ts:4:3 - error TS2564: Property 'uninitializedProperty' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

But `lib` specifies strict as false! It works fine if strict is just disabled. How can I configure Typescript so the projects are actually separate, and the code within each uses their own tsconfig options?

I've prepared an example repository here: https://github.com/gaggle/monorepo-tsconfig-experiment. Any thoughts and suggestions welcomed!

---

Just to put some context to my question: I'd like to move several projects to a single monorepo, but not all the code can use the same compiler options. The "strict" difference is an example of that, and I can't just fix the code so it all works with the same options.

Comment: I don't think `ts-node` builds the project using `--build`, but latter is required to activate the project references build. https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/897

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you. How would I get this working without ts-node? I can run `tsc -b` in app and see it builds `lib` which I didn't know would work, so I'm already learning. But the output still fails to run, I get errors like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`, so I don't even know how to run this outside ts-node.

Comment: `"main": "src/index.ts",` that needs to point to the `dist` version. "main" is what NodeJS tries to load when you import `lib`. In your case TypeScript is linked in "main", but TypeScript source can not be read by NodeJS. TypeScript builds to commonjs (per your settings) and puts its result to the `dist` folder. Use `"main": "dist/index.js"` and it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure why but `libs/lib`'s dist folder ends up with a `src` folder, so I've set its package.json field to `"main": "dist/src/index.js"`. I still get errors but I feel I might be missing some very basic concepts when I can't even explain why the `src` folder is in dist for libs/lib but not apps/app. But thanks for the tip, I've changed my sample repo to point main to JS.